# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python-3.6

i am getting 'object' has no attribute 'objects'. Here is my code from views.py

def product_list(request, category_slug=None):

```
    category = None
    categories = category.objects.all()
    products = Product.object.filter(available=True)
    if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
            products = products.filter(category=category)
    return render(request,'shop/prod/list.html' , {'category':category,
                                                                        'categories': categories,    
                                                                         'products': products   
                                                                      })
```

def product_detail(request, id, slug):

```
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id, slug=slug, available=True)
    cart_product_form = CartAddProductForm()
    return render(request,
                          'shop/prod/detail.html',
                          {'product': product,
                            'cart_product_form':cart_product_form })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
category = None
categories = category.objects.all()
```

You are setting category to None then immediately setting categories to a property of category, which can only be an error because None in python is the absence of a value.

You can check out more information on the official python docs here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None

Comment: but if set any other value instead of None then still there is same error with value name

Comment: What do you want to achieve with category? And also what is category supposed to be? Once we know hat, we can correctly troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: i am a beginner and want to build an online shopping project to enhance the django learning by this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jZ3DhppbUnM&t=183s

Comment: I think you should research more before beginning this project. From the looks of it, it is a pretty complex project. That being said, there are more bugs in your code, such as category_slug always being null since you set it to None in the method parameters. Try tackling  an easier project or check out some of the courses available online.

Comment: but this is all copied from the link that i shared with you

Comment: https://automatetheboringstuff.com this book is pretty good and available online. It’ll give you a basic introduction to python and explore many other functions of python. For web development, I suggest you check out Udacity.com or a similar website to take a course. It will teach you a LOT.